# How to check whether an xml file can be accessed or not in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io

I am saving dafault values to a xml file. If I don't have access to the xml file I should show a message in the status bar to the user. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Just try to open it, if you don't have access it will throw a System.UnauthorizedAccessException or if it is in use it will throw a System.IO.IOException, catch these exceptions and display an access denied message to the user.